# SWT color picker widget

Tags: swt, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-plugin

I want an SWT widget for color picker.The closest I could find was a color dialog box in which case a dialog box appears to select colour. But I want a drop down color picker.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any alone color picking widget other than ColorDialog in SWT. You can find other handmade components in open source projects, but it will not be easy to use them in your project 'cause of their dependencies.

You can look to [open source project code browser with color picker search](http://www.koders.com/default.aspx?s=color%20picker%20swt&search.x=0&search.y=0&la=Java&li=%2a&scope=&p=0) (be aware of different licences), especially to some particular codes [spket project color picker](http://www.koders.com/java/fid3F6FF0FA7A728DDAE229CAC016D4CDC466E116B8.aspx?s=color%20picker%20swt#L4), [perl editor color picker](http://www.koders.com/java/fid9808397718EE36F96D25A7F44CD740C11AE02E68.aspx?s=color%20picker%20swt#L18), [nattable color picker](http://www.koders.com/java/fidA31ED1D8FE04A401EB6D7A8D1B8642AB2969077D.aspx?s=color%20picker%20swt#L9), [jsc color picker](http://www.koders.com/java/fid3734345AAF90ECB4B109F7D8199DA5B91A40A5FE.aspx?s=color%20picker%20swt#L3)..